# WebCam Capture c# Logitech

Tags: c#, webcam-capture, logitech

I made this program for taking an Image from my Logitech HD Pro WebCam c920.

The program actually work for Integrated Camera, but when i want to take the flow of my Logitech Webcam
i have nothing... (No image, no errors).

I wanted to know if someone have the same problems or something to help me to fix it...

My program is only for taking an picture from my WebCam logitech on c# with aForge.

I have this code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Accord;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Webcam : Form
    {
 public Webcam()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        FilterInfoCollection filterInfoCollection;
        VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice;
       
        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterInfoCollection[cboCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videoCaptureDevice.NewFrame += VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame;
            videoCaptureDevice.Start();

        }

        private void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            pic.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
        private void Webcam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filterInfoCollection = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach(FilterInfo filterinfo in filterInfoCollection)
            {
                cboCamera.Items.Add(filterinfo.Name);
                cboCamera.SelectedIndex = 0;
                videoCaptureDevice = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            }
        }

        private void Webcam_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoCaptureDevice.IsRunning == true)
                videoCaptureDevice.SignalToStop();
        }
```

btnstart is button, cboCamera is a Combobox, and pic is a picturebox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture image from webcam Logitech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64556617/capture-image-from-webcam-logitech)

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. While I do not know why this occurs I have tested the following solutions:

1. Using [Media Capture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture) - Seem to work with all web cameras, but I had quite a bit of stability problems.
2. Using this [Versatile WebCam C# library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library) -  Seem to work fine.

I have not tested [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code)/OpenCV, but that is another alternative.